# List UART -> COM converter in Windows Device Portal

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi3, uart, windows-iot-core-10

I have Raspberry Pi 3 plate with connected USB to UART (COM) converter.
The power led on the USB stick is ON.
I can not find the converter in `Windows Device Portal`.
In both: connected and disconnected states I see just two UART related records in Device Manager:

```
        (ID:ACPI\BCM2835\0, Class:System, Manufacturer:Microsoft, StatusCode:25165834)
        >BCM283x Mini UART Serial Device
        (ID:ACPI\BCM2836\0, Class:Ports, Manufacturer:Microsoft, StatusCode:25182218)
        >ARM PL011 UART Device Driver
        (ID:ACPI\BCM2837\4, Class:System, Manufacturer:Microsoft, StatusCode:25165834)
```

Also I use `git diff` between saved device lists and there is no difference between the case I connect USB stick and disconnect it.
Where can I see the device in the list?

**UPDATE**

Here I print all found devices:

[image: Found COM devices]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need make sure your USB to UART (COM) converter is supported on Windows IoT Core. Please check the [hardware compatibility list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/learn-about-hardware/hardwarecompatlist#miscellaneous-1). The CP2102 USB 2.0 to TTL Module Serial Converter is supported.

I use CP2102 USB to UART Bridge Converter and it also works. Use the [SerialUART sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-iotcore-samples/tree/develop/Samples/SerialUART) can list two device: one is on-board PL011 UART Device and the other is mine.

[image]

From device portal:

[image]