# How to run IoTCorePShell.cmd

Tags: powershell, driver, windows-iot-core-10

I try to port Prolific USB to COM converter for solve my other problem: [List UART -> COM converter in Windows Device Portal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54629067/list-uart-com-converter-in-windows-device-portal)

I found this manual: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/learn-about-hardware/peripheraldrivers and copied all necessary files to separate folder:

- oem6.inf
- ser2pl64.sys
- serenum.sys

I installed:

- Windows 10 IoT Core Packages
- Windows Assessment and Deployment Kit including Windows PE add-on

Now I try to launch `IoTCorePShell.cmd` for run `New-IoTInf2Cab` as mentioned in the manual.
I tried both `cmd` and `Power Shell`, both with administrator rights and without.

In `Power Shell` I get:

```
PS C:\Users\olga\Desktop\COMDriver> New-IoTInf2Cab
New-IoTInf2Cab : The term 'New-IoTInf2Cab' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-IoTInf2Cab
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (New-IoTInf2Cab:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

How can I run `New-IoTInf2Cab`?

Comment: Have you imported the IoTCoreImaging module into your session?

Comment: I was need to clone the repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it was necessary to clone the repository.
The `IoTCorePShell.cmd` stay in the root.

https://github.com/ms-iot/iot-adk-addonkit